# Twitter4J - Looking up profile details without logging in

Tags: java, api, twitter, twitter4j

I've been using Twitter4J for a quite a while now, but I can't seem to find this particular feature.

I want to be able to search on a name, and when the certain user is on twitter, I want to retrieve basic information such as tweets, followers (like you can access via http) - but how to do is in Twitter4J? Neither the code examples or the source could help me.

Thanks,

William van Doorn

Comment: Thanks for adding the tag, Femeraf, I couldn't since I don't have 250+ reputation yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the following:
Twitter4J.api.UserMethods   That has the methods you seek.  The Twitter class directly implements it.

Comment: Thanks, and I guess I want .searchUsers() here? Does this work as I expect?

EDIT: How do I access these methods? I can't make an instance and they aren't static.

Comment: wvd thats the interface,so obviously you cannot instantiate it.  See my edits

Comment: I don't understand you? Could you give me a fast example of how to use it.

Comment: You want a fast example of the difference between an interface and a class in Java?

Comment: No, but TwitterFactory().getInstance() gives me a Twitter instance, however if I use .searchUsers() it says that I'm not authorized, this is what I mean. I don't want to authorize -- is this possible?

Comment: I've never used Twitter4J so I honestly don't know.  Maybe you should just abide by the security policy set in place instead of trying to be clever about it

Comment: I'll create a Twitter account and try it then. Thanks, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks, after creating an account it fixed my problem!

Answer (score 2):

I think u should use twitter4j library, get Access Token then create object of twitter and
and then call showuser() it will return user object then with the help of user object u will get all information of login user i will give a sample code to you.

```
    AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

    int i=twitter.getId();
    User u=twitter.showUser(i);
    System.out.println("user name"+u.getName());
```

Comment: upto name ok what about the profile image or avatar image for that user which method we used?

Answer (score 1):

My POM.XML

```
...
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
           <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
           <version>[4.0,)</version>
       </dependency>
  </dependencies>
...
```

My Class Test

```
import twitter4j.Twitter;
    import twitter4j.TwitterException;
    import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
    import twitter4j.User;
    import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

    public final class GetAccountSettings {

        private final String twitter_consumer_key = "oKu1emQJUGArI6kFNXNTCZ111";
        private final String twitter_consumer_secret = "g3EzljGP91AuqjBtIRjGFbKVEAg5cpxH96D6rWIgk4MbhK5111";
        private final static String oauth_token = "2847960911-LYoKllWcTo3VxZMdcLktWDPbLaeOywwrkf2W111";
        private final static String oauth_token_secret = "JoCajDpKvvzzOfsfQpar8aqIDmspyrGehvdj3YsCAp111";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            GetAccountSettings getAccountSettings = new GetAccountSettings();

            // Twitter Conf.
            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey(getAccountSettings.twitter_consumer_key).setOAuthConsumerSecret(getAccountSettings.twitter_consumer_secret)
                .setOAuthAccessToken(getAccountSettings.oauth_token).setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(getAccountSettings.oauth_token_secret);

            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

            User user = twitter.showUser("MR_Camaleon");
            System.out.println("\n ***************************    INFORMATION TWITTER PROFILE " + user.getScreenName() + "    ************************* \n\n");
            System.out.println("      Id:                    " + user.getId() + " \n");
            System.out.println("      Screen name:           " + user.getScreenName() + " \n");
            System.out.println("      Name:                  " + user.getName() + " \n");
            System.out.println("      Description:           " + user.getDescription() + " \n");
            System.out.println("      Image profile:         " + user.getProfileImageURL() + " \n");
            System.out.println("      Follorwers:            " + user.getFollowersCount() + " \n");
            System.out.println("      Friends:               " + user.getFriendsCount() + " \n");
            System.out.println("      Created date:          " + user.getCreatedAt() + " \n");
            System.out.println("      Language:              " + user.getLang() + " \n");
            System.out.println("      Time zone:             " + user.getTimeZone() + " \n\n");
            System.out.println(" ******************************************************************************************************");

        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to get account settings: " + te.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        }
    }
```